# Transform XML elements into elements with matching attribute names

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform the following XML:

```
<Summary>
   <assets>54</assets>
   <projects>471</projects>
</Summary>
```

into:

```
<Summary>
  <item name="assets" value="54"></item>
  <item name="projects" value="471"></item>
</Summary>
```

Can anybody, please help?

Thanks

Comment: Start with [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying). Add template to match `Summary/*`. Create `item` element (`<item name="" value=""/>`). Use [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to populate the attribute values (like `name="{name()}"`). Come back and update your question with code if you have problems.

Comment: This seems to belong to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532962/transform-xml-elements-into-attributes

Comment: No, I am realizing I need a different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As easy as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <item name="{name()}" value="{.}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```